# Android setStreamVolume to ZERO doesn't work in Android 4

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

I noticed that under Android 4.x setting ring volume to 0 is not possible. If I execute this code and then I go to Settings--> Sound --> Volumes I can see it is set to 1. I

```
audiomanager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, 0);
```

Do you know why? 
I know I could use audiomanager.setRingerMode(RINGER_MODE_SILENT) but annoys me!! because in this case I would have to "remember" if vibration is on or off for activating again sound.

Of course, all this works in other Android versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use [setStreamMute()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamMute%28int,%20boolean%29) as it has weird side-effects with the lifecycle of your process. See the docs:

> The mute command is protected against client process death: if a process with an active mute request on a stream dies, this stream will be unmuted automatically.

I'm afraid [setRingerMode()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setRingerMode%28int%29) with either [RINGER_SILENT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_SILENT) or [RINGER_VIBRATE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE)  is the way to go, which will have the effect of zero-ing out the stream volume

Answer (score 0):

try [setStreamMute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamMute%28int,%20boolean%29) instead which is equivalent to setting volume to 0.